# PM2 managed process doesn't respond after ~2 hours

Tags: node.js, socket.io, digital-ocean, pm2

I've set up a server on DigitalOcean which is developed using Node.js & Socket.io. The process is being handled by *pm2* version *3.0.4* on *fork* mode. The process doesn't respond after ~2hrs of the run. If I look at `"pm2 show"` or `"pm2 monit"` it shows the server is online.

To avoid this issue, I have also setup a cron job, which fires on every 1 hour.
`"0 */1 * * * /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/pm2 reload all"` however  this doesn't help either.

What is the issue? Currently, I have only one user who is testing it. I have a 2GB basic plan on DigitalOcean, and total memory used by the app had gone max to 60MB when I was monitoring (during which it stopped responding).

Can someone help me out how to prevent this issue?

**Update**
Updating the cron job to run the pm2 reload every 30 minutes has started resolving the problem. But, I am sure this is not expected.

`"*/30 * * * * /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/pm2 reload all"`

Comment: Could you take a look at the logs: "pm2 log yourprocessname"? Maybe we could see some indications for the cause..

Comment: @AndreyBulezyuk, sorry.. I don't have anything logged there, other than actual ```"console.log"``` I was doing.

Comment: Do you see after 2h when the server freezes the fork/child processes of pm2? Try hitting in console: "ps -aufx" and see for pm2 master process and look whether node fork-process is present. That may narrow the possible root cause

Comment: @AndreyBulezyuk I can see that ```PM2 v3.0.4: God Daemon (/home/user/.pm2)``` and also node process running ```node /home/user/example.com/server.js``` To surprice it has not stopped overnight.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and when I run `pm2 status` the process does not respond.

then I check  `~/.pm2/pm2.log` and I realize the process is not working because had not enough disk space for logs.

so I run :

```
pm2 flush all
```

and in my case that solve my issue.